# In 我只是为了让你觉得我在关心你，然后以此在逃避, who is escaping? Does it refer to an escape route?

Tags: translation

我只是为了让你觉得我在关心你，然后以此在逃避

I would translate it like: I just want you to think I care about you, and use this to escape.

My questions:

Who is escaping, the person talking or the person she's talking to?

然后以此在逃避 Could be referring to an escape route? Does the word route appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

> 我只是为了让你觉得我在关心你，然后以此在逃避

I just want you to think I care about you, 
and use this(refer the act"you think I care about you" or "I care about you", both could be right. Can not know since the information is not given)

to escape(from something. [Escape from what? it's not given]).

Comment: Does she care about her or is she just pretending? Or it can't be known?

Comment: @天照天照 who is "she"

Comment: A girl. She had just said to her friend what she really cares about her happiness. In reality she's sleeping with her boyfriend. That said she could still care about her friend as she loves her boyfriend as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the sentence, but i think the last sentence should be" 因此我在逃避，"rather than"以此在逃避" 
So, its means I am escaping.

Comment: Are you chinese? I'd like to know your chinese level before asking questions

Comment: @天照天照 yes, I am Chinese, I would like to say the Chinese sentence is a bit strange, I means the sentence is not fluent.